# How to use jQuery key up with google chrome numeric input?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, keyup

I have some jQuery code which works very well in Firefox. I use keyup events on numeric inputs. 
In Chrome works to but ofcourse only if I not use up and down mini buttons Google Chrome provides. If the user uses that mini buttons my code is irelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the "spinners" via CSS:

```
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Or you can use an `.on()` to catch both `keyup` and `change`:

```
$('#element').on('keyup change',function(){
    //your code
});
```

Comment: using .on() to catch both keyup and change works great.thanks

Comment: @impeRAtoR I'm glad it worked. Don't forget to accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I can use jQuery.change() It is not completely perfect but almost.